# Buggy technologies field (under the experience section)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

On Careers 2.0, the technologies field (part of each experience entry under the Experience section) does not work properly on Firefox. Could this please be fixed?

It is very hard to edit existing entries, especially when there are many.

Comment: Perhaps you could include a screenshot, so we can see what you're referring to?

Comment: Could you please specify what the problem is? As of now, it is very difficult to tell what you are asking.

Comment: I concur, on Chrome it is not the easiest to handle many tags in that field. I find that `Alt-Left` and `Alt-Right` help navigate between the tags, making it a *little* easier to manage.

Comment: Well, first of all: if I want to add new tag, I need to click existing and space for a new tag. Kinda complicated. If I want to add tag to the end, I need to very precisely click on some arbitrary point near the end but not clicking the tag itself. Then it throws me to the end. Sometimes, it send me to end, and I can't see any tags. So can't delete them. There should be a horizontal scrollbar or something on it to make it work like it's now. Or then I simply have no clue how to use it.

Comment: I can make it "work" by changing the width of div.tag-editor..

Comment: And here, I thought you were asking for a field under Experience where we could enter our experience with buggy technologies! ;)

Answer (score 3):

We recommend listing up to 5 technologies each for the Likes/Dislikes in the *Technologies* section:

[image]

Yeah, that helper text was temporarily broken, sorry - fix coming.

Editing a larger number of tags admittedly is a bit tedious right now, but it should work fine with only five or less.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Firefox (v25.0.1) myself, but I can't really reproduce this.

Clicking anywhere past the end of the tag list gives me a cursor at the end that lets me start typing a new tag.  Clicking any of the existing tag names (anywhere except on the "X", obviously) makes that tag name look like normal text and puts the cursor at the end of the name.

The one part I *can* reproduce is the lack of a scroll bar when the length of the list exceeds the width of the box, which I agree *is* somewhat annoying.  Then again, ordinary text input fields don't have scrollbars either, and I can still navigate the tag list just fine using arrow keys.

In general, the thing to realize about the tag entry boxes (including the Technologies boxes on Careers, as well as the ordinary tag entry box you get whenever you post or edit a question here) is that, despite their fancy appearance and AJAXy enhancements, fundamentally they're just plain old HTML `<input>` fields with extra bells and whistles.  As long as you treat them that way, they really work quite intuitively.